# Add unbound column to datagridview after setting DataSource property of grid?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I'm wondering how can I create and fill unbound columns values after setting DataSource property of DataGridView.
Suppose we have two simple table in our database:
tblTest:

1. ID (int)
2. Fname (nvarchar(50)
3. Population (int)

I have datagridview named grid in my form1:

```
DataTable tblTest = new DataTable();//Select * from tblTest
...
grid.DataSource = tblTest;
????
```

What will I replace with ??? to add unbound Percent column that show percentage of population over all data in tblTest rows.
**Our calculation must happen in code side not in DB side...**
thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add column to `DataTable` and use it in same way for adding to grid DataSource

```
DataTable tblTest = new DataTable(); //SELECT * FROM YourTable

//Calculate sum of population
Decimal overall = tblTest.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<Decimal>("Population")).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum();

tblTest.Columns.Add("Percentage", typeof(Decimal));
foreach(DataRow drow in tblTest.Rows)
{
    Decimal percentage = YourPercentageCalculationResult; //Add you calculation

    drow.SetField<Decimal>("Percentage", percentage);
}

//Create column "on runtime"
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn temp = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
temp.DataPropertyName = "Percentage"
temp.ReadOnly = true;
grid.Columns.Add(temp);

grid.DataSource = tblTest;
```

Comment: My purpose is altering Grid columns not datatable!

Comment: Add column through designer or with code. Set `DataPropertyName` to   "Percentage". Datatable already contain "unbound" - calculated column of percentage

Comment: Dear Fabio I wanna add column and set it's value in run time.

Comment: Thank you,If the population value updated by user then will percentage value recalculate?

Comment: No, then you need play with event `DataGridView_CellEndEdit`. Where you can check if value of population was changed and update a percentage value